# mobile media queries used if screen is zoomed on desktop

Tags: css, mobile, media, desktop

Im using media queries to load my css like so:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mobile.css" media="(min-resolution:1.25dppx),(-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:1.25),(min-device-pixel-ratio:1.25)">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="desktop.css" media="(max-resolution:1.24dppx),(-webkit-max-device-pixel-ratio:1.24),(max-device-pixel-ratio:1.24)">
```

which seems to work fine (haven't tested fully, yet). However, if I zoom the test page on desktop to say 150%, and refresh, then the mobile stylesheet is loaded?

It is important that the queries still work correctly with zooming on desktop for this site.

How can I fix this?